# Dúvida sobre declarar uma classe com if(!class_exists) no PHP

Tags: php

Gostaria de uma ajuda para entender melhor a lógica desta situação abaixo.

Um arquivo principal faz um *include* de outro arquivo que contém apenas uma *classe*.

**/main-file.php:**

```
require_once('/other-file.php');
new ExampleNameClass( 'arg1', basename( 'arg2' ) );
```

**/other-file.php:**

```
if( !class_exists('ExampleNameClass') ) {
  class ExampleNameClass {
  [...]
```

Pelo que entendi, o arquivo que declara a classe, só vai entrar na condição se a classe *NÃO* existir `(!class_exists)...`. Porém ela **realmente não existe**, então achei essa condição desnecessária.

Alguém poderia esclarecer o motivo da pessoa ter feito desta forma? Tem algo relacionado a segurança?

Comment: Assim você pode criar a sua própria class "ExampleNameClass" personalizada, mas caso não exista ele carrega a dele.

Comment: Em geral, em vez de fazer isso é usado apenas o `require_once` ou `include_once` para que um mesmo arquivo não seja importado duas vezes, e assim não sobre escrever algum dado, como uma classe. Se você tem dois arquivos diferentes com duas classes com o mesmo nome, então deveria juntar ou mudar os nomes das classes

Comment: Serve também — a grosso modo — para evitar o erro `PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class`. Caso a classe seja carregada antes (em algum outro arquivo), isso evita que um outro código crie/carregue uma classe com o mesmo nome, gerando o erro supramencionado.

Comment: Obrigado pessoal! A resposta do @WictorChaves encaixa perfeitamente na lógica do sistema. Realmente eu poderia ter criado a minha classe personalizada, sem precisar alterar o arquivo dele.

Comment: Não sei todas as condições do sei código, mas no geral seria melhor você criar uma classe que herda da classe existente, ao invés de sobrescrever.